# Menu not show woocommerce product category

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I have problem with configure wordpress woocommerce. On this time I write theme for woocommerce but I can't add product category for menu.

On this address We can see "Product Category"  [Link.](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/docs-menus/)

But my menu section view that:
[image]

How I can get product category ? And I know, I can add it via own link. I need some plugin ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is simple:

**Go to appearance - menu**

select your screen options 
[image: screen options]

**Select product  categories:** 
[image]

**Enjoy  the product categories select**

[image]